# How many possible combinations of 3 groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Here is the problem. This is not homework, it's an actual problem a friend and me are trying to solve. We have a dataset of answers, where 10 students answer at most 20 questions. So some students do not answer all questions.

The task: we need to form 3 groups, G1, G2 and G3, and distribute the students throughout the groups. The constraint is that for each group we would like the maximum number of questions to be answered. So if question 1 is answered by 4 students in G1, 4 students in G2, and 0 in G3, this is not a preferred arrangement. It would be preferable to shift students from G1 and G2 to G3. So a question that is answered in each group with the same ratio has a higher score than a question answered in all groups but concentrated in a single group. The solution to the problem is to maximize the score.

So, how do we know how many arrangements there are? And how to we find it??

Comment: Can you formalize what the score is? For example, what's better: a $(0,3,3)$ split or a $(1,1,4)$ split?

Comment: The max score is a uniform distribution, so $(2,2,2)$ scores higher than $(1,1,4)$ and $(0,3,3)$.